# How I can run multiple processes parallel but inside each process execution sequential

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am working on CSV files
in my code I just download 5 files from ftp server and then process these files.
I want to download all 5 files first and then start processing.

it is about products against every product there are 5 files, I actually want parallel execution  for products but sequential execution for downloading and processing them. I did it with `Parallel.ForEach` but it doesn't work for me it download 3 files and start processing or download 2 files and start processing and then download remaining files.

I simply want to download all files first then start processing them, but parallel processing between products

Here is `Parallel.ForEach` (calling method)

```
Parallel.ForEach(dt.AsEnumerable(), row =>
                {
                    //code here 
                    Products(eSetting, row);
                });
```

Actual method that download and process files:

```
public static void Products(ETLServiceSettings eSetting, DataRow row)
{

    IEnumerable<string> Datafiles = GetFilesInFtpDirectory("ftp://");
    foreach (string file in Datafiles)
    {
        string file_Name = "";

        if (file.ToLower().Contains(".csv"))
        {
            productId = Convert.ToInt32(row["ProductId"].ToString());

            file_Name = DownloadFile("ftp://");
        }
    }

    string targetDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\" +
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InProcessETLFiles"].ToString() + "\\";

    List<string> vfiles = new List<string>(), sfiles = new List<string>(),
        ufiles = new List<string>(), psfiles = new List<string>(),
        sufiles = new List<string>();

    foreach (var fileEntries in Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory))
    {
        //Files processing code is here
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileEntries);
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(info.FullName);
    }
}
```

First the `foreach` on top should be complete and then execute the next `foreach` for processing files.

Comment: You have answered your own question you want to download the files then process them in parallel, so have a function for getting the files then process each file in parallel.

Comment: public static void Products(ETLServiceSettings eSetting, DataRow row)
        {
            DownloadFiles(eSetting, row);
            ProcessFiles(eSetting, row);
        }
i make it as but it doesn't work download one file and go on processing method and then download remaining files and then process them

Comment: i am not able to screenshot of console due to less reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split up the Programs function into the downloading component and the processing component. Do your downloads in the parallel for each, then call your processing function. Parallel for each returns when all processes are complete.

Comment: thanks! 
i split it into two Parallel.Foreach one for downloading second for processing it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Some psuedocode

```
files = getfiles
foreach file in files
process(file)
next
```

Comment: i want to run completely the downloading foreach and then process all the downloaded files not want to process file in foreach

Comment: You want to so all the downloads simultaneously then process them after they have all downloaded.